# Get users for multiple ASP.NET web applications from same Membership db

Tags: asp.net, membership

I have two web applications, one web-facing and a back office application. Both are using the same membership database but their users are defined by the application id. I want to be able to access the users for the web-facing application from the back office. Is this possible?

I assumed I could do Membership.GetAllUsers() but as I'm in the back office when I do this it only brings back the users for that application. Can I specificy which application I want to users for? i.e. Membership.GetUsers("*theapplicationid*") or something?

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you using the standard membership providers? One way could be to write your own provider, overriding the Application part.

Comment: Hmmm, was hoping there was a way around it without having to write my own but it seems nothing is simple! Thanks for the info :-)

Comment: That can be done in about 10 lines of code. You inherit from your current (SQL?) provider, and just override the one `Application` property. I'll get a fresh cup of coffee, and when I'm back, you're done.

Comment: OK I may have to come back to you for some more pointers! Any chance of some sample code?

Answer (score 0):

If all of your users have access to any of your sites you can use the same application name for all sites. Here is an old but still valid [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/Always-set-the-_2200_applicationName_2200_-property-when-configuring-ASP.NET-2.0-Membership-and-other-Providers) to ScottGu’s blog explaining the "why" and "how".

The caveat of this approach: You have to convert your existing membership database to use just one application name.

Comment: The back office users only have access to the backoffice and vice versa. I don't want to give them access to all applications.

Comment: You can make this distinction by introducing the two roles „backoffice“ and „web“ in a system with only one application / membership database.

Comment: I like this idea! Thanks :-)